# custom collectd plugin will not compile

Tags: c, collectd

I am trying to write a custom plugin in C for collectd and cannot get it to compile with collectd. I've tried [this tutorial](https://wiki.opnfv.org/display/fastpath/Collectd+how+to+implement+a+simple+plugin) and could get the plugin to work with the collectd build system.

I've also tried [this](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Build_system) with just a copy of the load plugin, and tried to manually compile the c-file in order to just link the compiled library (kind of a hackish way around). But I'm still getting errors.

When I run

```
gcc -I. -g -O -c load_copy.c -lcommon
```

I get this error

```
daemon/common.h:308:2: error: #error "Don't know how to convert between host 
and network representation of doubles."
 #error                                                                         
\
  ^
daemon/common.h:336:23: warning: ‘struct passwd’ declared inside parameter list
            struct passwd **pwbufp);
                   ^
daemon/common.h:336:23: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
load_copy.c: In function ‘load_read’:
load_copy.c:184:2: error: #error "No applicable input method."
 #error "No applicable input method."
```

like there is still a compilation error. Has anyone successfully written a C plugin for collectd? Any tips?

This is from common.h

```
#ifdef HAVE_LIBKSTAT
int get_kstat(kstat_t **ksp_ptr, char *module, int instance, char *name);
long long get_kstat_value(kstat_t *ksp, char *name);
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_HTONLL
unsigned long long ntohll(unsigned long long n);
unsigned long long htonll(unsigned long long n);
#endif

#if FP_LAYOUT_NEED_NOTHING
#define ntohd(d) (d)
#define htond(d) (d)
#elif FP_LAYOUT_NEED_ENDIANFLIP || FP_LAYOUT_NEED_INTSWAP
double ntohd(double d);
double htond(double d);
#else
#error                                                                         \
    "Don't know how to convert between host and network representation of 
doubles."
#endif
```

Comment: Can you also post the code around line 308 of the `daemon/common.h` file? There must be an `#ifdef` check or something that the header file is doing and fails so that `#error` is evaluated.

Comment: It's on github, https://github.com/collectd/collectd    https://github.com/collectd/collectd/blob/master/src/daemon/common.h  I wouldn't think this should break since I literally copied load.c https://github.com/collectd/collectd/blob/master/src/load.c and tried to compile it manually as a another plugin. I changed the includes #include "collectd.h"

#include "common.h"
#include "plugin.h"      to daemon/common.h , etc

Comment: Paths on github can change or the project can be deleted.  Please put a [mcve] directly in the question.

Comment: My guess is that you didn't run `autoconf` and `./configure` before `make`

Comment: This is from common.h

Comment: I ran autoconf and ./configure and make when I was trying to get it work with the build system of collectd. And that didn't work. Now I'm just trying to use gcc to compile a single plugin, then drop that compiled library in and put it in autoconf. Shouldn't that work too?

Comment: Did `./configure` generate a `config.h` file (or similar)? You should also include that file, this file might have the necessary `#defines` calculated during `./configure` like `FP_LAYOUT_NEED_NOTHING` or `FP_LAYOUT_NEED_ENDIANFLIP`

Comment: I don't know if ./configure generated it. But in src/daemon there is a configfile.c and configfile.h. I tried including the .h file to load_copy.c. Still got the same error

Comment: `./configure` will generate a file `src/config.h` (see [`configure.ac`](https://github.com/collectd/collectd/blob/master/configure.ac#L5)) where the checks performed by `./configure` are stored as `#define`s. The endianes checks starts at line 1297 of `configure.ac`. Perhaps you are using the wrong header file which is not supposed to use by the library users.

Comment: Thank you! That got me past that problem, I ran ./configure again and then found src/config.h. I then included config.h in the .c file, and generated a shared library with the following: gcc -I. -g -O -c -fPIC myplugin.c -shared -o myplugin.so. Now I'm seeing the error "dlopen myplugin.so failed...The most common cause for this problem is missing dependencies. Use ldd(1) to check the dependencies